# PHP session variables lost after header() redirect

Tags: php, session

I've explored the various solutions to this question on Stack Overflow though none seem to work for me.

Here is my problem. After running a php script on my website, I've added a header function to redirect me to another page like this:

```
header("Location: https://example.com/examplepage.php");
exit();
```

After this redirect, `examplepage.php` tells me that there are no session variables set (even though they are).

If I visit another page on the website after the redirect, the session variables seem to appear again and everything works fine again. So I'm assuming this is an issue with the header redirect.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

**Attempted Fixes**

- Including `session_start()` immediately after opening a php tag on all pages
- Including `exit()` after the header redirect
- Removing all whitespace before and after the `<?php` and `?>` tags

**PHP Snippet of examplepage.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../scripts/dbh.php';

    //checks if the user is logged in
    if((isset($_SESSION['id']))){
        //do stuff
    }
    else{
        //redirect user to login page as they are not logged in
        //this header is executed as it thinks $_SESSION['id'] is not set
        //note that this code is functional, only doesn't work after the header redirect mentioned
        header("Location: https://example.com/login");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please show us more of your script that includes the session_start etc.

Comment: @Dave Question has been updated with example

Comment: Follow the link Luke West posted ... it covers just about everything that might be causing you a problem. It looks like you are missing `exit;` after your call to `header`.

Comment: are both pages `https`? Maybe also you redirect from `www.*` to `non-www.*`?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou That did it! I was redirecting from `www.` to `not-www.`. Simply added `www.` to the header redirect and it worked. Had no idea that would cause a problem. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :) Voting to close as a duplicate since the answer that Luke linked already contains that.